# treating categorical/binary variables in lm

Tags: r, regression

When building the regression function using `lm`, do we need to explicitly specify which variables should be categorical or binary? If we have to, how to do that? Thanks.

Comment: maybe this answers your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26822526/regarding-handling-many-binary-independent-variables-in-lm/26822927#26822927

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This brings up another important question:  Is whether a variable is numeric or categorical a property of the data or a property of the analysis?

Back in the early days of statistical computing it was easier to store categorical variables as numbers and therefore it was necessary to designate at some point that these variables were indeed representing categories rather than the numbers themselves having meaning.  The common place to designate this was at the point of analysis.  This results in a legacy of having the variable type be a property of the analysis.

R (and others) is a much more modern language and takes the approach that this should be a property of the data itself.  This simplifies things in that you can make this designation once and all resulting analyses/graphs/tables/etc. will treat the variable properly.  I think this approach is much more intuitive and simple, after all, if a particular variable is categorical for one analysis, shouldn't it be categorical for all analyses, graphs, tables etc.?

This has been a bit of a long answer, but the idea is to help you shift your thinking from how to designate this in the analysis to thinking how to designate the properties for the data itself.  If you designate that your data is a factor (using the `factor`, `ordered` or other functions) before any analysis, then the R analysis/graphing/table tools will do the correct thing.  Depending on how your data looks and how it was entered/imported, this conversion may have already been done for you.

Other properties, such as the order of the categories, should also be properties of the data, not the analysis/graph/table/etc.